# ROBLOX sandboxing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to sandboxing in Lua, and would like to learn how to filter stuff like :GetChildren() or :Kick().

This is what I have so far:

```
function safeGetChildren(obj)
    local objs = {}
    for _,v in pairs(obj) do
        if not v.Name:match("^^") then
            table.insert(objs, v.Name)
        end
    end

    return objs
end

function safeClearAllChildren(obj)
    if obj:IsA("Player") or obj:IsA("Players") or obj:IsA("Workspace") or obj:IsA("ServerScriptService") or obj:IsA("Lighting") or obj:IsA("ReplicatedStorage") or obj:IsA("StarterGui") then
        return error("Cannot clear this object!");
    else
        obj:ClearAllChildren();
    end
end

function safeRemoveObject(obj)
    local name = obj.Name:lower();

    if obj:IsA("Player") or  name == "remoteevents" or obj.Parent == "RemoteEvents" or obj.Parent == "ReplicatedStorage" or obj.Parent == "StarterGui" or obj.Parent == "ServerScriptService" or obj.Parent == "TinySB" then
        return error("Cannot destroy this object!");
    else
        obj:Destroy();
    end
end

local Globals = {
    -- Globals
    workspace = workspace,
    print = print,
    error = error,
    table = table,
    pairs = pairs,
    game = game,
    string = string,
    _G = _G,
    getfenv = getfenv,
    loadstring = loadstring,
    ipairs = ipairs,
    next = next,
    os = os,
    pcall = pcall,
    rawequal = rawequal,
    rawget = rawget,
    rawset = rawset,
    select = select,
    setfenv = setfenv,
    setmetatable = setmetatable,
    tonumber = tonumber,
    tostring = tostring,
    type = type,
    unpack = unpack,
    _VERSION = _VERSION,
    xpcall = xpcall,
    collectgarbage = collectgarbage,
    assert = assert,
    gcinfo = gcinfo,
    coroutine = coroutine,
    string = string,
    table = table,
    math = math,
    delay = delay,
    LoadLibrary = LoadLibrary,
    printidentity = printidentity,
    spawn = spawn,
    tick = tick,
    time = time,
    UserSettings = UserSettings,
    Version = Version,
    wait = wait,
    warn = warn,
    ypcall = ypcall,
    PluginManager = PluginManager,
    LoadRobloxLibrary = LoadRobloxLibrary,
    settings = settings,
    stats = stats,

    -- Functions
    ["require"] = function(...)
        return error("Cannot require object (API disabled)");
    end,
    ["getchildren"] = function(...)
        return safeGetChildren(...);
    end,
    ['children'] = function(...)
        return safeGetChildren(...);
    end,
    ['clearallchildren'] = function(...)
        return safeClearAllChildren(...);
    end,
    ['destroy'] = function(...)
        return safeRemoveObject(...);
    end,
    ['remove'] = function(...)
        return safeRemoveObject(...);
    end,
    ['kick'] = function(...)
        return safeRemoveObject(...);
    end,
    ['saveplace'] = function(...)
        return error("Cannot save place (API Disabled)");
    end
}
setfenv(1, Globals)
table.foreach(workspace:GetChildren(), print)
```

I made this in a few hours but things like :GetChildren() aren't filtered in this environment. If anyone can help me with an explanation on what each part of the code required does will really help.

Comment: You would have to wrap every object.

Comment: How would I wrap objects?

Comment: That is complicated and broad. But basically you replace each one with a table and use __index and __newindex to handle getting/setting members.

Comment: Can you link me to documentation so that I can learn please?

Comment: I do not believe they are official docs but if you PM me on roblox (warspyking) I will certainly get back to you with a more detailed explaination. But as it stands this question may be a little too complicated for SO, and I reccomend accepting vlad's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting safe wrapper under name 'getchildren' in new environment. But later, when testing, you're calling 'GetChildren', taken from 'workspace' table, and not from global variable in new environment.
  Replacing function in global environment doesn't mean replacing functions with same name in all tables/objects. For that to work, object must call function from current global environment, and not function from internal tables or lexical closures.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @Jacob, I don't know what's exact implementation of workspace:GetChildren(). But if you want it sandboxed only by replacing global environment, it must be itself a wrapper, calling global function. Say, `function workspace:GetChildren(...) return GetChildren(...) end`, and that GetChildren must be placed in global environment. Good libs don't pollute global env with its internals, so that's not the case.

Comment: How would I do this with something like p:GetChildren()? THings like that would happen too?

Comment: You'll have to replace p:GetChildren() within actual 'p' instance, if implementation allows it. Say, if 'p' is a table, you can assign `p.GetChildren = safeGetChildren`. But sometimes it's not possible, if 'GetChildren' comes from metatable.